# update table from array with different values where empty field

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem with my code, problem is data not update still NULL.

table A

```
year | period | code | user_id 
2013 |      4 | 1231 | 
2013 |      4 | 1232 |
2013 |      4 | 1233 |
2013 |      4 | 1234 |
2013 |      4 | 1235 |
```

Table B

```
user_id | user_name | cash
A1      | AB        |   10
A2      | BC        |    5
A3      | CD        |    7
```

I will put table B user_id to table A user_id when cash >= 7

Table Result

```
year | period | code | user_id 
2013 |      4 | 1231 |      10
2013 |      4 | 1232 |       7
2013 |      4 | 1233 |
2013 |      4 | 1234 |
2013 |      4 | 1235 |
```

here my code,

```
    $arr = array();
    $query = mysql_query("select user_id from tableB where cash >= 7");
    while ($arrs = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $arr[] = $arrs[0];
            }
    $count = count($arr);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE tableA SET user_id ='$arr[$i]' WHERE year = 2013 and period = 4 and user_id IS NULL");
    }
    if ($sql) {
        echo "success";
    }
```

Comment: And what exactly is your problem here?

Comment: table not update, still NULL

Answer (score 0):

The operator in the query should be `>=` and not `=>`

check on this:

```
$arr[] = $arrs[0];
```

this now holds the first record of the result set. Expected that there is only one record with cash >= 7, that might be ok, but thats a risky assumption.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE tableA SET user_id ='$arr[$i]' WHERE year = 2013 and 
                            period = 4 and user_id IS NULL");
    }
```

in here `$arr[$i]` iterates over the fields of the first record, giving you in a sequence the values 'A3', 'CD' and 7 and you are running three useless updates on your table. Afterwards the column `user_id` in Table A has the value 7 and not 'A3' since this is the last value in your loop.

Comment: yes, type mismatch (=> should be >=). but problem still same. I print_r() from array, result is OK. I confuse why not update at all

Answer (score 0):

I have solution for my code,

```
$arr = array();
$query = mysql_query("select user_id from tableB where cash >= 7");
while ($arrs = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $arr[] = $arrs[0];
        }
$q = mysql_query("select code from tableA order by code");

    $index = 0;
    while($codes = mysql_fetch_row($q)){
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE tableA SET user_id ='".$arr[$index++]."' WHERE code='".$codes[0]."'");
}
```

result perfect !

thanks all